# How to set ribbon on image by stacking it in a div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I currently have an ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
<div class="repeaterDiv" data-ng-repeat="item in itemArray">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="imageClass" ng-src="{{item.image}}"/>
    <div class="corner-ribbon bottom-right sticky green shadow">Changed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS pulled from this [codePen](https://codepen.io/eode9/pen/twkKm):

```
.corner-ribbon{
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.corner-ribbon.sticky{
  position: fixed;
}
.corner-ribbon.shadow{
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.corner-ribbon.bottom-right{
  top: auto;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.corner-ribbon.green{background: #2c7;}
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the ribbon to be restricted to the wrapper class.  Does anyone know how I can do that? so I'm still using the same ribbon, but instead of being in the bottom right of the screen, it is at the bottom right of the image for which it applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `relative`/`absolute` `position` and reset `display` of `.wrapper` to shrink on image. Then add `overflow:hidden` to cut off edges of ribbon:

```css
.corner-ribbon {
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.corner-ribbon.sticky {
  position: absolute;
}
.corner-ribbon.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.corner-ribbon.bottom-right {
  top: auto;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.corner-ribbon.green {
  background: #2c7;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;/* or inline-block or float */
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="repeaterDiv" data-ng-repeat="item in itemArray">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="imageClass" ng-src="{{item.image}}" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
    <div class="corner-ribbon bottom-right sticky green shadow">Changed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class has fixed positioning.

```
.corner-ribbon.sticky{
  position: fixed;
}
```

So for exact css you may not be able to attach ribbon to each img, rather ribbon would go to specific place in window only. However, you can adjust css a bit. Make wrapper class relative, and .corner-ribbon.sticky absolute position. Then adjust your css fot top/bottom/left/right properties to align them.

```
    .wrapper{
      position: relative;
    }
    .wrapper .corner-ribbon.sticky{
      position: absolute;
      /* put top/bottom/left/right values here*/
    }
```